# Avoid throwing full stack trace to soap client

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am using SOAPFaultException to customize my response whenever I need to raise an exception. But in case of exceptions like NullPointerException, full stacktrace of my code gets sent to client. I was wondering is there a way in jax-ws to customize all non-SOAPFaultException? So instead of showing full stacktrace, I'll say something like "Internal Server Exception"?

Thanks!

Comment: Case closed or still a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can disable the inclusion of the stack trace in the SOAP fault
>   message by setting the
>   `com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace` Java
>   startup property to `false`.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-soapfaults.htm#BABGDDEA

The chapter [Using Unmodeled Faults](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-soapfaults.htm#BABHGIIF) in the same document has some explanation and a reference to SOAP Message Handlers. This would allow you to tweak processing of unmodeled faults i.e. `RuntimeException`s.